# Xampp server not getting installed

Tags: installation, xampp

[Screenshot:-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iW9F1.png) I am trying to install Xampp (xampp-win32-5.6.23-0-VC11-installer) but it stopped at attached screenshot. I have waited for 5 hours, but it's not getting completed. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved I have installed vc_redit86 file from this link https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=48145 then restart the system and install again.

Answer (score 0):

Is your windows OS architecture a 32-bit one?

Did you try running as administrator?

Try downloading a new installer - sometimes it gets corrupted and you need to re-download...

Comment: Yes, its 32 bit. I tried with as an administrator also but still same result.. I downloaded twice still same issue..